# Apply Microsoft Office's theme to my windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-office

Is it possible to implement theme of Microsoft Office in my windows application.

I mean when anyone changes theme of Microsoft Office it should also make change the theme of my windows application.

If its possible, let me know how to do that?

Comment: winforms doesn't support theming. You're looking for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that what you're asking here is quite possible. Then again I may be wrong. As far as I know, the only way to use Microsoft Office-like visual styles with your application is either by using a third party application or creating the custom controls yourself (wouldn't recommend that, hours of coding and designing). In other words, you would be better off using a suite like [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/), but please be aware that it is not free.

Here's a result of an application implementing these controls (taken from the developer's website):

[image]

I'm sure if you make a Google search, you could possibly find free alternatives to this software.